# My Mac computer won't recognize an external WD Drive via USB

Tags: peripherals

It worked in the past, but I forgot to eject it before unplugging it and it gave me that dire warning about never doing that again!

Now it won't recognize it at all when plugging in.  I searched online for answers, and found that many people have probs with these irksome drives, but no answers yet.

Help?!

Comment: Head on over to SuperUser.com -- this question will be there shortly.

Comment: Should probably be on superuser.com.

Comment: I guess the first thing to do would be to open the Disk Utilities (Applications, Utilities) if the HD itself is there and "just" lost it's main partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed itself. It might have been that I installed [a WD support download](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=111&sid=59&lang=en) but I think it's more likely it just needed time.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem with a FAT32 HD. I just plug it to a Win PC, eject it properly and it was then ok to be plugged on the Mac.